# Ajax async call for new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

today I am stacked with some question about async work of jquery ajax.I am pretty new to js and especially for jquery.

After click on button new tab opened and filled with pretty long request(a lot of data returned) and freeze other part of site (tab wi button) until request is done.
Is there any possibilitty to make it work async, so my old tab will work while request computating?

Current js code for open new window

window.open(request, '_blank')

Which one obviously not async

May be something like

Var O = window.open() ;
O. Ajax(blablabla)

UPD:

I solved problem by creating new  element with rel="norefferer" and imitate click on that element, so new tab will open in new process and don't block main tab

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  You're going to need to give us a lot more details.  For a start, exactly what is `request`?  From your question, it sounds like it's not just a simple `url`.  So maybe that's your solution - provide a url instead and load the data from the server (asynchronously as per a normal request).   Remember that javascript is **single threaded** so if you're doing any js processing against the new window/tab, it will freeze up your existing tab.

Comment: Request return huge amount of text data(write a lot directly in output stream in Java as text). So while it rendering at another tab, it freeze main tab

Comment: I think the simplest answer is: don't.   Instead, rethink your design. maybe with a a modal dialog or having the tab load its own data.

Answer (score -1):

AJAX **is** async (it literally means "asynchronous JavaScript and XML").

You just need to use it properly, as follow :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com",
    "success": function(result) {
        // This part will be called after the ajax request was successful
        /* 
        insert your code here, 
        but be aware that, as CBroe noted in the comments, 
        window.open() could be blocked by modern browser 
        */
    }
 });
```

Read [the jquery documentation on AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine... From my understanding OP wanted to do window.open() AFTER the async call was a success. But the question was vague and the "how to make ajax working async" didn't make any sense, so I tried to clarify.

Comment: _"You just need to use it properly, as follow"_ - that is not really proper to begin with though. Most browsers these days, in default settings, will _block_ any popups, that are not opened tied _directly_ to a user interaction such as a click. If anything, you'd need to open a "blank" popup _before_ the AJAX request (so directly tied to the click action the user triggered the whole process with), and then write the result of the request into the popup afterwards.

Comment: In my opinion popup windows should never be used... My answer was about AJAX, what OP is trying to do with it is not of my concern. I edited my asnwer to include your remark into it.

Comment: May be my explanation of problem is pretty weird. I'll try again. Now I have button, after clicking on it opens new tab with request, that fill this new tab with very huge amount of text. When this tab processing, my tab with button freezed. So I want to open new tab and call request for text, but continue to work with main tab so I want async request on second tab

Comment: Then I recommend opening an empty popup window containing only the ajax request necessary to load the content. The Ajax request should not be launched on the main page.

Comment: Thanks for answer